# Php substr and trim

Tags: php

I want to read the last line of a block of text , e.g:

> 250-SIZE 31457280
>
> 250-AUTH LOGIN CRAM-MD5
>
> 250 OK

Here is my current code - it reads the first line only:

```
if (substr(trim($res), 0, 3) != "250") {
```

Giving an output of

> 250-SIZE 31457280

I want to get the last

> 250 OK

(there are no blank lines in between it's my copy paste problem ). Any idea?

Comment: Which api do you use to read that data? You might be interested in http://docs.php.net/fgets or http://docs.php.net/socket_read (with PHP_NORMAL_READ) to get the result line by line.

Answer (score 0):

Am I right in thinking that `$res = '250-SIZE 31457280 250-AUTH LOGIN CRAM-MD5 250 OK'`?

If it is, then the following should serve your purpose:

```
$last_set = substr($res, (strlen(trim($res)) - 6), strlen(trim($res)));
```

This will output `250 OK`.

Comment: Yes, this should still work - although I have only tested it using `\n` literals.

Answer (score 0):

to get the last "250" from try

```
$string="250-SIZE 31457280 250-AUTH LOGIN CRAM-MD5 250 OK"
echo substr($string, strlen($string)-6, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could explode the result by "\n" and take the last element of the array

```
$arr = explode("\n",$res);
$lastone = $arr[count($arr)-1];
```

replace linebreak if differs on your system, but should be fine in my experience

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if the occurence of 250 OK is at the end you could try reversing both the string your looking for and the string your searching in (else you would have to type look for KO 052, which is hard to read)

```
if (strpos(strrev($res), strrev('250 OK')) === 0) // 0 since it should be at start, but not false
{
  ... do things
}
```